# CSS Issue Centering NavBar

Tags: css, center, navbar

So, essentially the last time I ever did any web-page development, there was only HTML, and I didn't have anymore than a basic understanding anyways. So now, I'm playing catch up and trying to learn CSS. My issue is a horizontal navbar, which doesn't stay perfectly centered. I've tried adjusting widths, and borders, and margins but I'm missing something.

With my current layout, there is a tad more whitespace on the left than the right, and I am stuck.

Here's the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PkvZ7/

CSS:

```
<!-- JASCO NAVBAR -->
ul
{
width:100%;
list-style-type: none;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding:none;
overflow:hidden;
}

li
{
align:center;
width:20%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
}
a:link,a:visited
{
display:block;
width:100%;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:20px;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#FF6103;
text-align:center;
padding:5px;
text-decoration:none;
font-variant:small-caps;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#000000;
color:#FF6103;
}

#container {
  width:100%
}

<!-- TOP CSS-->
.top {
position:absolute;
width:80%;
height:10%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-top:20px;
margin-right:auto;
color:#000000;
padding:0;
}

<!-- CONTENT CSS-->
.content {
position:absolute;
width 100%;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
padding:3px;
color:#dddddd;
}

#img
{
}

<!-- TOP IMAGE CSS-->
img.center {
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jascostyle.css">
<title>Single"Frame" Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
  <center>
  <div class="top">
  <img class ="center" width="80%" height="5%" href="#temp" src="#temp" alt="JASCO ENERGY"/>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>


  <div  class="content">
  <h1>This is under construction!</h1>
  </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I appreciate any help/explanation on this matter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a fixed width + `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto`. You should not be using absolute positioning for your content - let it flow naturally.

The `<center>` tag has been deprecated, so use the same technique for your outer "container" wrapper with a width of 960px;.

```
ul {
    width:500px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:0;   
}
```

In general when using list-based menus, use `float:left` on your LI, use `display:block` on the A-tag and put all other styling on the A-tag, not the list itself.

See my tutorial: [I Love Lists](http://preview.moveable.com/jm/ilovelists/).

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, so I attempted the changes. It still isn't quite center (I also updated the JSFiddle) Also, why specify pixel width instead of percentages? I would like very much for the navbar to resize, unless there is some big reason I shouldn't have it do so.